# Use custom classes IEquality by default rather than specifying it as a parameter?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it possible to have the `Dictionary<>` class use the `IEqualityComparer` specified inside the class it's using as its key rather than specifying it as a parameter every time I construct it?

```
    public class mytest : IEqualityComparer<mytest>
    {
        public string name = "foo";
        bool IEqualityComparer<mytest>.Equals(mytest x, mytest y) { return x.name == y.name; }
        int IEqualityComparer<mytest>.GetHashCode(mytest obj) { return obj.name.GetHashCode(); }
        public override int GetHashCode() { return name.GetHashCode(); }
    }
```

...

```
    var a = new Dictionary<mytest, int>();
    a.Add(new mytest(), 1);
    a.Add(new mytest(), 2);//does not throw error...bad!

    var b = new Dictionary<mytest, int>(new mytest());
    b.Add(new mytest(), 1);
    b.Add(new mytest(), 2);//will throw error...good!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to override the **Equals** and **GetHashCode** methods of *mytest* or implement **IEquatable**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.80).aspx

> Dictionary requires an equality implementation to determine whether
>   keys are equal.
>
> You can specify an implementation of the
>   **IEqualityComparer** generic interface by using a constructor that
>   accepts a comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation,
>   the default generic equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default is
>   used.
>
> If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic interface,
>   the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot to override the `Equals()` method after doing `GetHashCode`